# Any idea why some outlets might be colored red in a Barcelona apartment?

Tags: power, barcelona

In an apartment I visited in Barcelona, there were several electrical outlets in a row. Two of them were colored white, but one was colored red. They're right next to each other, so it seems there must be something different about the red one, but I'm not sure what. They all work perfectly fine, so it's a question mostly just for curiosity. Unfortunately I don't have a picture.

Comment: probably not the case : in companies, red outlets can mean they are the one on backup power, but I don't imagine it being the case for a living apartment. Other possible option : this outlet is managed by a mural switch (for lights). It is the case in my appartement in france excepte the outlet is not differentiated. Now you mention it, next time i need to change it, i will ensure to use one a different color.

Comment: @dna What is probably not the case? They're likely not different all?

Comment: Where were the outlets located specifically? @dna is correct that this usually indicates backup power. Any chance that the apartment building used to be a hospital, nursing home, or assisted living facility?

Comment: @travelgasm I doubt that was it was previously any of those types of facility. One of the outlets was located in the dining room of the apartment.

Comment: @MichaelMior Interesting. So there were a lot of these red outlets in the apartment?

Comment: @travelgasm That's the only one I recall. There may have been another one or two, but not everywhere.